# How to import a jar package into my IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

I have the following basic project class set up. How would I import the jar file into that project? [image]

Comment: you mean [Correct way to add external jars (lib/*.jar) to an IntelliJ IDEA project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051640/correct-way-to-add-external-jars-lib-jar-to-an-intellij-idea-project)

Comment: the official documentation is extremely clear and well written on explaining how to do what you are asking ( as it is on everything else as well), what part of it, specifically do you not understand?